# Error "Value cannot be null parameter name: method" while building in project Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp

I am getting an error when building app in Xamarin.Forms

> "Value cannot be null parameter name: method".

It was working fine previously. Now when I am opening the project and trying to run it, I am getting this error.

I having Visual Studio 2019 and Xamarin.Forms 4.6.0.847.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these steps:

- Close Visual Studio.
- Open Project Folder for which you are building the app (in my case it was UWP).
- Delete **bin** and **obj** folders.
- Open Visual Studio and your Project.
- Clean Your Solution.
- Now build and Run your application.

Comment: Did not help for me